# Query showing only most recent date in a field without all SELECTS being in the GROUP

Tags: sql, max, inner-join

** Rewritten for clarification. ** I have looked at well over a dozen posts on multiple sites trying to figure this out and tried applying things mentioned - all without luck. I have a query joining 3 tables. I use MAX(date) in the SELECT area along with 9 other fields. Something I'm doing requires me to list all of those fields in the GROUP BY area in order for the query to run. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Ideally, I'd like the query to return only 1 record for a person based upon the most recent entry. So a person, who has a unique ID may have 3 records because of 3 dated entries. I want that one row with the most recent date entry. Sorry if that's clear as mud. Ideas? TIA!

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT s.ID, s.FIRST_NAME, s.LAST_NAME, a.ADDR1, a.CITY, a.STATE, a.ZIP, e.EFF_DT, e.TERM_DT, MAX(e.MEPE_EFF_DT)
FROM SUBSC s

INNER JOIN ADDR a 
on s.SID = a.SID

INNER JOIN ELIG e
on e.EID = s.EID

WHERE a.GID = 99
AND e.ELIG_IND = 'Y'

GROUP BY s.ID, s.FIRST_NAME, s.LAST_NAME, a.ADDR1, a.CITY, a.STATE, a.ZIP, e.EFF_DT, e.TERM_DT

ORDER BY s.LAST_NAME ASC
```

Comment: Very verbose table and column names, makes it very easy to understand without further explanation... Which one is the users id in `table_3`?

Comment: I guess I should have written that as e.2 = s.2. Table 2 has 2 ID's - 1 links to table 1 and one links to table 3 in order to get all the data needed.

Comment: I've edited the query to hopefully clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `group by`.  You want filtering.  One method is:

```
select t1.*
from table_1 t1
where t1.date = (select max(tt1.date) from table_1 tt1 where tt1.? = t1.?);
```

Your query is a bit unclear on what columns are what.  The `?` is for the column that identifies each customer.

Comment: I've rewritten it to hopefully clear up what I've got thus far.